# How to customize a component on React Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm trying out React Bootstrap and want to change the customize the nav. I'm doing something like this.

```
const navInstance = (
    <Nav bsStyle='pills'>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href='/home'>NavItem 1 content</NavItem>
    </Nav>
);

React.render(navInstance, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Any thoughts as to how do I change the color? Also, how would I affix the nav to the top, such that when the page scrolls, the nav stays fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing the Navbar component as the parent. Your component should look something like the following:

```
<Navbar fixedTop>
    <Nav>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href='#'>Link</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={2} href='#'>Link</NavItem>
    </Nav>
</Navbar>
```

The fixedTop prop will keep it fixed by adding the appropriate classes from the bootstrap.css. The changing of the colors would be an override of the css classes and you should be good to go.

Comment: What does the `eventKey={1}` refer to?

Comment: It's an identifier that gets sent with the onSelect callback on the Nav element to identify what was selected.