# How do I custom-edit React bootstrap components?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

This thread does not answer my question: [How to customize a component on React Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550854/how-to-customize-a-component-on-react-bootstrap)

What am I asking for is not how to merely add custom css, and change a few colors. I am asking about how do I get rid of the controls and indicators, and then create a new slider component for the carousel that would control the slides, or move the controls and indicators beneath the carousel.

This is what I want to do:
[image: Carousel and thumbnail slider]

How do I custom-build this thumbnail slider into the bootstrap carousel without even having access to the HTML? I don't understand how am I supposed to do this? From React bootstrap, I can only import the `BsCarousel.Item`. How do I get rid of the controls and indicators, and should I even do that, or should I somehow move them beneath the body, and if so, how do I move them? How do I go about doing this?